# Why was crocodile (תנין) from Exodus 7:10 translated as snake or serpent?

Tags: hebrew, exodus

In Exodus, chapter 7, verse 10, Aaron throws his staff of the ground in front of Pharaoh and it becomes a *תנין* in [the Hebrew Bible](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0207.htm) as well as the [Leningrad Codex](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%207&version=WLC).

[The Septuagint](http://bibledatabase.net/html/septuagint/02_007.htm) translates it as *δρακων*, which reads similar to "dragon", most importantly, it distinguishes it from the *נחש* at verse 15, which translates as *οφιν* (serpent or snake).

Yet, English translations don't differentiate the words, and translate both as snake or serpent. [KJV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%207&version=KJV) translates both as *serpent*, and [NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%207) as *snake*. Many other translations translate them as the same, ([YLT](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%207&version=YLT) does translate *תנין* as monster).

It should be noted that in modern Hebrew *תנין* is a crocodile (or an anligator) and a *נחש* is a snake.

What is the reason for the crocodile turning into a snake in the English translations?

Comment: Related ?  http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/11484/why-is-pharaoh-called-the-great-dragon-in-the-book-of-ezekiel

Comment: A crocodile is a reptile, as is a snake. That is the common denominator between the two. Perhaps the word in question simply means reptile, and has been translated into the most staff looking of the reptiles;  the snake.

Comment: It’s worth noting that the Aaron’s dragon has actually “drunk up” not “eaten” other dragons -  “κατέπιεν” in LXX,  as a river includes its tributary. So they may have turned into some liquids. And so a snake may have appeared a better analogy to the translators who knew what it was about.

Answer (score 11):

It should not be assumed that since the modern Hebrew word for "crocodile" is *tannin*  that the word meant the same thing in the time of Biblical Hebrew. Sometimes lingual shifts are minor, but other times they are significant. For example, in Biblical Hebrew, *'olam* means "for length of days" (often understood as the closest term to eternity preserved in Biblical Hebrew). However, in Mishnaic Hebrew, *'olam* had come to mean "world."<sup>1</sup>

The *tannin* are larger creatures in the Bible. They are typically taken to be either river or sea creatures ([Genesis 1:21](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Genesis+1:21); [Psalm 74:13](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Psalms+74:13); [Job 7:12](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Job+7:12); [Isaiah 27:1](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Isaiah+27:1)). However, [Deuteronomy 32:33](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Deuteronomy+32:33), [Isaiah 34:13](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Isaiah+34:13); and [43:20](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Isaiah+43:20) all refer to land creatures with the term.

This is the creature that Aaron's staff turned into.

> [Exodus 7:10](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Exodus+7:10) When Moses and Aaron went to Pharaoh, they did so, just as the Lord had commanded them – Aaron threw down his staff before Pharaoh and his servants and it became a *tannin*.

*Tannin* is used 28 times in the Hebrew Bible. In some of those, it is parallel to another word that helps in this discussion. (In some, it is parallel to words that we don't yet know the meaning of because they are only used once or twice.)

> [Deuteronomy 32:33](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Deuteronomy+32:33) Their wine is *tannin*’s poison, the deadly venom of *phthanim*.

While the exact identification of the *pethen* is unknown, it clearly refers to a venomous snake here and in other places where it appears. Whether that is an adder, cobra, or asp doesn't matter.<sup>2</sup> The important thing here is that the venomous snake *pethen* is parallel to *tannin*. Then in Psalm 58:4, *pethen* is parallel to *nachash*.

> [Psalm 58:4](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Psalms+58:4) Their venom is like that of a *nachash*, like a deaf *pethen* that does not hear.

Thus we see that *pethen* are *nachash*, snakes. Therefore, since *pethen* are also referred to with *tannin*, we know that *tannin* can be snakes.

From looking at these occurrences, we see that *nachash*, *tannin*, and *pethen* are synonyms. From looking at them, I would say that they form up like this:

*tannin* - large or otherwise dangerous reptiles, of which snakes are included. They can be either land or sea creatures.

*nachash* - a general term for all snakes or serpents. All *nachash* are *tannin*, but not all *tannin* are *nachash*.

*pethen* - a specific type of venomous snake. All *pethen* are *nachash*, but not all *nachash* are *pethen*.

The modern English translators, being aware that *tannin* was not limited to "crocodiles" in the Biblical Hebrew era, chose the word "snake" as "snakes" are part of the *tannin* and it was already established that Moses' staff became a snake. They did this because English does not have a word that corresponds 1-to-1 with *tannin*. In the modern, western mind, "dragon" usually conjures up images of flying, fire-breathing reptiles. That isn't the image we get from the Hebrew (those *tannin* stayed on the ground and Aaron's ate the others. The people didn't flee and weren't pushed away from several tons of flying reptile appearing in their midst).

Just like the Hebrew *tannin*, the Greek term *drakon* was wider than the English term *dragon*. You are right to say "it reads similar to *dragon*." While the words are related, they are not a perfect match. [In Greek mythology](http://www.theoi.com/greek-mythology/dragons.html), a dragon might have wings and legs or it might not.

- [Ladon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladon_%28mythology%29) - a drakon that did not have legs but coiled around a tree. It was slain by Heracles.
- Apollo fought [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28mythology%29), which is always seen with neither wings nor legs in ancient Greek artwork.
- The [chimera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimera_%28mythology%29) had a serpent's head on a lion's body (along with a lion's head and a goat's head), and thus was a legged dragon.

In fact, **most** Greek dragons were giant serpents and few had legs or wings (Demeter and Meda used winged *drakons* to pull their chariots).  Like the *tannin*, the *drakon* could be in the sea (cetea-type drakon) or on land (chimera or serpent-like). There was even a subtype of *drakon* with faces and upper bodies of beautiful women (the Dracaenae).

In short, the LXX used *drakon* for *tannin* in Exodus 7 because *tannin* and *drakon* had similar ranges of meaning. The English translators use *snake* because we do not have term with such a similar range of meaning as *tannin*. Translators try to avoid having a plethora<sup>3</sup> of translator's notes at the bottom of every page.

---

### Notes

<sup>1</sup>In one of my Hebrew classes, the professor threw us a verse from the Mishnah using *'olam* on the first day of the Mishnaic unit just to make this very point about lingual shifts.

<sup>2</sup>I would not use the general term "viper" as "viper" also appears in parallel to the *phethen* in Job 20:16. "Viper" is a translation of *'eph'eh*.

<sup>3</sup>*translator's note.* Spanish for "many." See what I mean? :)

Comment: I'd be curious if ancient Hebrew even has a word for crocodile. Since southern Egypt is likely the only place the Hebrew culture would have encountered crocodiles, a word for 'crocodile' probably would have first entered the Hebrew language as a loan word from ancient Egyptian. @FrankLuke, do you happen to know if something like this was the case?

Comment: @DavidH, [The Jewish Encyclopedia](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/4771-crocodile) says the ancient Hebrew word for crocodile is unknown. There are a couple of candidates in the Hebrew Bible, but nothing described quite fits. It's a good article on the critter.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and the article link. It was a good read. I hadn't heard of the Jewish Encyclopedia before.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Hebrew is more about the creatures purpose rather than appearance. So tannin is just serpent but with legs. Or tannin isn't serpent but predator the tannin of the sea could be the shark.. As jackal is tannin of the dessert.

So Satan is that old tannin (predator).

Comment: Hi Charles, welcome to BHSE, thanks for your contribution! Please do take the [Site Tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about the site and the SE format. This answer could be improved by supplying some supporting sources or references.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's reasonable to consider the culture context in this instance, namely, the connection with the Egyptian tale titled 'The Wax Crocodile', see https://ancientegyptonline.co.uk/westcar-wax-crocodile/

In the case of the Egyptian story, an inanimate object is brought to life, similar to the biblical account. Irrespective of the reptile being a serpent or a crocodile, the Egyptians would have gained respect for the "magical abilities" of Aaron through Moses, especially with the literary context already in place.

Comment: Hi Joe, welcome to the site. This is a helpful look at the culture and its relation to the text, +1. Could you clarify how you believe the Egyptian culture influenced the translation decision? Please be sure to take the [site tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour), and thanks for contributing!

Comment: It's probably less the culture driving the translation, and moreso Yahwe using a form of "magic" readily attested to by the Egyptians. It would have legitimized Moses as a "god" and Aaron as his "priest". Happy to comment more if you have additional questions.